# Creating a list using mutable sequence methods in Python fails

Tags: python

These work:

```
>>> print [1,2,3] + [4,5]
[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> 'abc'.upper()
'ABC'
```

This doesn't:

```
>>> print [1,2,3].extend([4,5])
None
```

Why? You can use string methods on bare strings, so why can't you use methods on bare sequence types such as lists? Even this doesn't work:

```
>>> print list([1,2,3]).extend([4,5])
None
```

N.B. For a colloquial meaning of 'work'. Of course there'll be a good reason why my expected behaviour is incorrect. I'm just curious what it is.

---

P.S. I've accepted soulcheck's answer below, and he is right, but on investigating how the addition operator is implemented I just found that the following works:

```
>>> [1,2,3].__add__([4,5])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But presumably the **add** method doesn't modify the underlying object and creates a new one to return, like string methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`extend` works, just doesn't return any value as it's modifying the object it works on. That's a python convention to not return any value from methods that modify the object they're called on.

Try:

```
 a = [1,2,3]
 a.extend([4,5])
 print a
```

edit:

As for why one reason for this could be that it's sometimes ambigous what the method should return. Should list.extend return the extended list? A boolean? New list size?

Also it's an implementation of [command-query separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation), ie. if it returned something it would be a query and command in one and cqs says it's evil (although sometimes handy - see `list.pop()`).

So generally you shouldn't return anything from mutators, but as with almost everything in python it's just a guideline.

`list.__add__()` is the method called when you do + on lists - it returns a new list.

Comment: Whereas strings are immutable, so string methods can't modify the original object, so they do return a value? Which doesn't work for say tupples because although they are immutable like strings, they don't have any methods because only mutable sequences have methods. Or something. Accepting!

Comment: @SimonHibbs exctly. string and list examples you gave create a new string/list. One reason for this convention can be that it's sometimes ambigous what the method should return. Should list.extend return the extended list? A boolean? New list size? Also it's an implementation of [command-query separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation), ie. if it returned something it would be a query and command in one == evil. I'll put it in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the design of the interface. Extend does extend the list but does not return any value.

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
l.extend([4, 5])
print l
```

Comment: Naming the list "list" is discouraged, because you need a meaningful name. But in sample code discussing lists, what's more meaningful?

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Of course you are right. I just didn't think when typing this code.

Comment: @ugoren It is also discouraged because you are shadowing the standard `list` class.

Comment: @ugoren - I would say it is *especially* discouraged in sample code, as many newcomers look to online samples to pick up good coding practice and style.